# How do I export a JPG with the same color profile as my Photoshop workspace?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, color, color-profile

I created a design for a webpage in Photoshop and got all the colors looking perfect.

However, when I export it to a jpeg and view it outside of Photoshop the colors are completely different.  If I open the jpeg in Photoshop the colors are correct again.

Think this is something to do with the color profile?  Photoshop seems to be using the North America General Purpose color profile.

How can I make the jpeg look the same color as in photoshop?

Can I convert the file? I hope I don't have to redo it!

Thanks

Comment: Which colour profile are you using? Do you know the difference between CMYK and RGB? RGB is typically for screen use (so JPEGs), and CMYK is for print.

Comment: Thanks but it's not to do with that - it is RGB.  I'm using North America General Purpose color profile

Comment: I'm having this same issue but I can't find the 'Embed Color Profile' setting anywhere!

Comment: You need to export using "covert to sRGB" for the web. It is the world wide standard for web browsers. Find it in the Save for Web dialog.

Answer (score 2):

In the Save For Web Dialog, check the "Covert to sRGB" box.

[image]

Comment: It is checked. I can make the Save For Web preview look correct by changing the Preview drop down menu to Use Document Profile but that's only for the preview.

Comment: Where are you viewing the images outside of Photoshop? A browser (which one)? some other app? Have you calibrated your monitor?

Comment: It looks exactly the everywhere except photoshop because photoshop is the only one using a specific color profile

Comment: You have not answered my questions.

Comment: I fixed it! I just needed to check the box saying embed color profile on save for web!

Comment: THat doesn't fix it. Not all browsers are color managed. And if you expect all web users to be using a color managed browser, your'e mistaken. I suspect the bulk of the problem is your monitor is not calibrated properly. You should really never need to embed a color profile in a web image.

Answer (score 1):

if working in "Adobe 98 rgb", then when exporting as jpeg, both 'embed color profile' and 'convert to srgb' should be checked